# A simple question concerning simple functions.

Tags: measure-theory

**Claim**: Let $X$ be a set and **X** be a $\sigma$-algebra. If $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are simple functions, then the function $\psi$ defined by $$\psi=\max\{\phi_1,\phi_2\},$$ is also simple.

**Proof. [Attempt]** Let $$\phi_1=\sum^{m}_{k=1}a_k \chi_{E_k}$$ and $$\phi_2=\sum^{n}_{i=1}b_i \chi_{F_i}$$ be the standard representations of $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$, respectively. Consider the collection $\{E_k\cap F_i|k\in\{1,2,...,m\}, i\in\{1,2,...,n\}\}$. Note that $\bigcup{E_k\cap F_i}=X$. On each $E_k\cap F_i$, $\psi$ takes on one exactly one value. Hence, $\psi$ takes on at *most* $nm$ values; therefore, $\psi$ is simple. $\blacksquare$

Did I miss anything here? Thank you!

Comment: Why do you claim the union of the intersection is the whole space? The indicator function of the rationals is a simple function but your claim would not be true in this case. Also each your simple functions can take n+1 and m+1 values respectively when counting zero.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It appears my understanding of simple functions is lacking. I will try to construct a proof using the facts Peter Tamaroff supplied below.

Comment: @ChristianBueno, I thought that union of intersections would indeed equal the whole space X for the following reason. (I will prove just one direction of the inclusion since the other is obvious.) Let $x\in X$. Then, $x\in E_k$ for exactly one $k$ since the collection $\{E_k\}$ partitions $X$. Similarly, $x\in F_i$ for exactly one $i$ since the collection $\{F_i\}$ partitions $X$. Hence, $x\in E_k\cap F_i$, which is a subset of $\bigcup E_k\cap F_i$.

Comment: @dgc1240 If I were you I would just answer my own question.

Comment: @dgc1240
If I define $\phi_1=\phi_2=\chi_\mathbb{Q}$ then $E_1=F_1=\mathbb{Q}$ are the only sets involved and $\bigcup E_k\cap F_i = \mathbb{Q} \neq \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @ChristianBueno, just include $a_0=0$ and $E_0 = \phi_1^{-1}(0)$, similarly for $\phi_2$.

Comment: @Sanchez
That would work, but the OP didn't specify if the simple functions were in any particular standard form. Nevertheless, whether or not the sets combine to the whole space shouldn't effect how the proof should work.

Comment: @ChristianBueno, I did indeed mention that the simple functions were in their "standard representation." :)

Comment: @dgc1240 Ah that's true. Perhaps you should elaborate on the meaning of standard form in your post. I never learned of any particular standard form so I just assumed you meant sum of linear combination of indicator functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\max\{\phi_1,\phi_2\}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\phi_1+\phi_2\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left|\phi_1-\phi_2\right|.$$

Comment: Thank you! After proving that simple algebraic combinations of simple functions are simple, I simply (no pun intended) used the identity you supplied above. One final question: was my proof completely wrong? Since this is a self-study, I like to reflect on ways to improve. In particular, I like to know where incorrect proof went wrong. Thanks again!

Comment: @dgc1240 I think your proof is correct, but you should clarify what you take the union over.

Comment: Notice that this involves exactly the same steps I detailed. For example, to prove that $|\phi_1-\phi_2|$ is simple, one has to show that $\{x:\phi_1(x)\geq\phi_2(x)\}$ s in the $\sigma$-algebra or something equivalent to it.

Answer (score 1):

- Show that the sum and product of two simple functions is simple.
- If $\phi$ and $\psi$ are simple functions, show that the set $U=\{x:\phi(x)\geq\phi(y)\}$ is a set in the $\sigma$ algebra.
- Conclude what you want, using the fact that $$\max\{\phi,\psi\}=\phi\cdot\chi_U+\psi\cdot\chi_{X\setminus U}.$$